# GridView losing an image on Orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, gridview

I'm a beginner learning android fundamentals working on my first app. My app consists of a gridview of images. A click on each image opens up another activity with some details about the image. I have used Picasso for loading all the images. 
The problem is that when the screen is rotated, I have used onSaveInstanceState() to save the state of the fragment and also avoided getting images from the server again. Here is the fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", movielist);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

I'm fetching the saved state in onCreateView of the fragment like so

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        movielist = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    }else{
        movielist = (ArrayList<Movie>) savedInstanceState.get("key");
    }
```

Like mentioned above, I use the list that I just retrieved with the adapter like so

```
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_img_view);

        Log.v(LOG_TAG + SIG, "setup ImageAdapter");
        mMovieAdapter = new ImageAdapter(gridview.getContext(), imageView, movielist);
        gridview.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
```

To prevent further fetching of data, I do the following in onStart of fragment

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    String SIG = "onStart";
    Log.v(LOG_TAG + SIG, "Entering");
    super.onStart();
    if(movielist.size() == 0)
        fetchMovies();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG + SIG, "Exiting");
}
```

This is the crux of the code in getView of the adapter

```
  if (convertView == null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG + SIG, "Convertview is null");
        GridView.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutParams.height = height / 2;
        layoutParams.width = width / 2;
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG + SIG, "Convertview is not null");
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Log.v(LOG_TAG + SIG, "Calling picasso with: " + moviePosterPaths.get(position));

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(moviePosterPaths.get(position).getMovieUrl())
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(imageView);
```

The issue that i see is as follows

1. On rotation of screen from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait, the first image in the grid is empty...shows a white patch. All other images are ok.
2. If I click on one of the images that are visible it goes to a detail activity and when i return, the image that was blank is now visible
3. If I try to scroll, the entire grid just disappears leaving behind a white background.

I wanted to post screen shots but I don't have enough reputation points. I would really appreciate help.